# Non Generic Versions of Generic classes and interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I often find myself in a situation where I create a generic interface or class and then want to use different versions of this class or interface in a non generic way. For example I may have an interface like this:

```
interface ICanCreate<T>
{
    T NewObject();
}
```

Which allows a class to be a factory for that type. I then want to register these with a general factory class, so I try to write something like this:

```
public class Factory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, ICanCreate> mappings; // what do I put here????

    public void RegisterCreator<T>(ICanCreate<T> creator)
    {            
    }

    public T Create<T>()
    {            
    }
}
```

In the dictionary which type do I use for my value? I don't know if I am missing some sort of design principle and I am aware that this has a lot to do with co(ntra?)variance. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either have to just use `object` in your dictionary declaration (it's all private, and *you* can verify that you'll never put the wrong kind of thing in there) or declare a non-generic `ICanCreate` interface which `ICanCreate<T>` extends.

Basically you want a type relationship which can't be expressed in C# - and whenever that happens, you end up with a slightly unpleasant solution, but it looks like you can isolate the ugliness here (i.e. keep it within the single class).

Comment: What would you say is the most preferred one of the two? I always go for solution number two if I am in this situation, believing that it is a more elegant solution. Is it, or does it not matter?

Comment: Are there any members you could sensibly put in the non-generic interface? If the interface is *just* the Create method, then I'd stick with object - the non-generic interface wouldn't actually give you anything. In other cases, you may be able to get away with only referring to the non-generic interface where you don't know the right type argument, in which case that provides an obvious benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, this is a problem that is solved in C# 4.0:

```
public interface ICanCreate<out T> // covariant
{
    T NewObject();
}

public class Factory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, ICanCreate<object>> mappings = new Dictionary<Type, ICanCreate<object>>();

    public void RegisterCreator<T>(ICanCreate<T> creator) where T:class
    {            
      mappings[typeof(T)] = creator;
    }

    public T Create<T>()
    {            
      ICanCreate<object> creator = mappings[typeof(T)];
      return (T) creator.NewObject(); // I do not think you can get rid of this cast
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. what does that mean? Do you have a link with more info on that or something?

Comment: Eric Lippert's series on covariance and contravariance is one of the best explanations on the net. It starts here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look at that =) Is the `out` marking thing mentioned there as well, or is that something new in C# 4.0? If new, do you have something about that somewhere?

Comment: Those articles was written before the new syntax was finalized, so Eric uses + and - instead of out and in. Most articles about the new features in C# 4.0 will mention the new support for co/contravariance. Here is one: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx